# Moq - Extracting Mock DataSet & Context to a Separate Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test which verifies that a function adds exactly one record to an Entity Framework dataset like so:

```
var internals = new Mock<DbSet<InternalTransaction>>();
internals.Setup(q => q.Create()).Returns(new InternalTransaction());

var mockDC = new Mock<IDataContext>();
mockDC.Setup(q => q.InternalTransactions).Returns(internals.Object);

// Removed:  set up some data for my test
mockDC.Object.DoSomeFunction(data);

internals.Verify(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<InternalTransaction>()), Times.Once());
```

Since I have a lot of tests to do with this context, I'm trying to extract the mock stuff to a separate class, like so:

```
public static class DataContext_Creators
{
    public static Mock<IDataContext> CreateMockContext()
    {
        var internals = CreateMockDataSet<InternalTransaction>();
        var externals = CreateMockDataSet<ExternalTransaction>();

        var mockDC = new Mock<IDataContext>();

        mockDC.Setup(q => q.InternalTransactions).Returns(internals.Object);
        mockDC.Setup(q => q.ExternalTransactions).Returns(externals.Object);

        return mockDC;
    }

    private static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateMockDataSet<T>() where T : class, new ()
    {
        var mockDataSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockDataSet.Setup(q => q.Create()).Returns(new T());
        // some other stuff, Provider, GetEnumerator, etc
        return mockDataSet;
    }
}
```

... and change my test to:

```
mockContext = Common.DataContext_Creators.CreateMockContext();
context = mockContext.Object;

// Removed:  set up some data for my test
context.Object.DoSomeFunction(data);

//internals.Verify(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<InternalTransaction>()), Times.Once());
```

But now that I can't access "internals" anymore, how can I do the .Verify() statement?  context.InternalTransactions won't work because that returns "internals.Object" (which it needs to for the method I'm testing to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that object you may once again regain Mock object of it by using Mock.Get() method. Look at example:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentId { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Entity entity = Mock.Of<Entity>();
    var mock = Mock.Get<Entity>(entity);
    mock.Setup(e => e.ParentId).Returns(11);
    var result = entity.ParentId;
    // now result == 11
}
```

You could use Mock.Get method on your internals.Object

Comment: So it sounds like I should be able to do this in my test:  var mockInternals = Mock.Get<IQueryable<InternalTransaction>>(context.InternalTransactions);   mockInternals.Verify(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<ExternalTransaction>()), Times.Once());  -- however, the e.Add does not compile ("cannot resolve symbol 'Add'").

Comment: Because you are getting Mock of IQueryable<InternalTransaction> type and indeed IQueryable<> does not have Add method. But InternalTransactions is Mock of DbSet<InternalTransaction>. Try var mockInternals = Mock.Get<DbSet<InternalTransaction>>(context.InternalTransactions); mockInternals.Verify(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<ExternalTransaction>()), Times.Once());

Comment: Ah, that works!  I also realized that when I edited my code for this post, I mixed Internal & External--I edited my original post to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new utility class with 2 properties:

```
Mock<IDataContext> DbContextMock
Mock<DbSet<InternalTransaction>> InternalTransMock
```

Have your Utility function return this new object so your test has access to both.

Comment: I have tried this, and it works.  Downside is, I need to add one of these for every table I need to access.

Comment: can you define the class using using generics so that it accepts any type of db table?

Comment: Unknown; I'm going with another answer because it aligned better with the way I was approaching this.  Thanks.